# Settings API with custom post type menu limitation

Tags: custom-post-types, options

I've created a custom post type menu with `register_post_type`. I want to add a settings sub-menu with lots of options, including extra "Add option to a select list" button.

The problem: when using settings api, any `<form>` wants `action="options.php"`. But that ends with a redirect to the edit.php address required when the sub menu is added to the custom post type menu. That means `$_POST` is lost by the time the code get back to the options page - so there is no way to see if those extra buttons were pressed.

Not using options.php for the <form> directs the submits directly to edit.php, where it dies with a permissions option. I'd prefer not to use JavaScript to fill in those dynamic settings. Any way to bypass the settings API and `options.php`, and get directly the edit.php but not get the permissions crash?

I looked at the source code, as well as tons of plugins with custom post type and a settings page, but they ALL use settings API via `options.php` - and that precludes getting an alternate submit button click back to the settings code. In this case, this is a severe limitation with the Settings API because the redirect at the end loses `$_POST`.

Answer (score -2):

For less of problems, you can use Advanced Custom Fields plugin for create a good options page , and custom fields into posts, pages, and so on.

Plase check it here:

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/ - Paid addon.

Plase see a video.

Comment: A link only answer is considered poor quality. If it's behind a paywall even more.